# Structure of a particular cokernel

Tags: ring-theory

Let $f:\mathbb Z^3 \to \mathbb Z^3$ be given by
$$(a,b,c) \mapsto (44a-8b-58c,-72a+6b+84c,30a-30c).$$

What will be structure of the coker(f)?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Your map has the matrix form
$$ M_f = \begin{bmatrix} 44 & -72 & 30 \\ -8 & 6& 0 \\ -58 &84  & -30 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now you can do row operations to compute the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of the matrix, and from there you can read off the structure of $\mathrm{coker}\ f$.

**EDIT**: Yes, the normal form gives the cokernel. It has the form $$ \hat{M_f}  = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & a_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_3 
\end{bmatrix}$$
such that $a_1 | a_2 | a_3$ (if all of them er non-zero). In your case, the diagonal matrix in the normal form is $$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 &0& 30\end{bmatrix}$$
This means that $\mathrm{coker} f$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/2 \oplus \mathbb Z/6 \oplus \mathbb Z /30$. (the computation was done in `Macaulay2` with the command `prune coker M`.

Comment: but how does smith normal form gives the structure of cokernel?...

Comment: @sayak: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks,,but one thing I also want to know for clarification does  smith normal form applies equally well for determining the d's in the rational canonical form for all modules over pid??